# Use X Ray in BGE

Tags: game-engine, materials, objects

How can I activate X Ray to an object in BGE?
so, it will always be visible, even when other objects are over.
I tried activating X-RAY option in Object tab, Display. I also red about using Z-Offset in materials, but that don't worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using add 2D filter and *imageRender* for additional camera and mix two images together in GLSL

[image]

[Blend files](https://github.com/KorolevAndrey/UPBGE-BGE-Blender-Python-GameDev/tree/main/Silhouette%20Outline%20POST%20Effect)